# Logic required for Comparison in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Structure is as following.

```
+---------------+
|    Type 1     |
+---------------+
|Below 50 (Red) |
|50<100 (Orange)|
|150<200 (Green)|
|200 Above(Blue)|
+---------------+
```

as there will be Type `2,3,4` need to check when I pass value like say `75` which should be `between 50 < 100` and the structure should be in table Type `1,2,3,4`.
How can I do this possibly, I need a query to check between them. I can hard code the matter easily which i can pass the values for stored procedure but i need this table for match and check the colors i need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: it doesn't matter need the logic SQL Server would be appreciated.

Comment: _I need a query to check between them_ Alright, you need a query, but first to get it you need to show us what did you try too. Also your question is not clear enough.

Comment: These values are stored in table as i told above already, that i can hard code say value is 85 it falls between 50 < 100 then color is orange i can use comparison through if else by easiest way but how can i use table to retrieve the color from the table which ever these fall.

Comment: Why don't you normalize the data into three columns, lower/upper bound & color? Then it's a simple (join) condition: `where val between lower and upper`

Comment: That because you have a bad design there, this is the first problem, there is a lack of normalization. Does this table hold many ranges or just those?

Comment: I already told you there are type 1,2,3,4 i gave you only type 1 example table would contain 2,3,4 with similar type values but ranges will vary.

Comment: Oh and color is fixed Red,Orange,Green,Blue.

Comment: @dnoeth i can use between operator easily but if the value is above 200 how would it work .. ? I used fixed 100000 data in it or is there any other way.

Comment: @NamanKumar: Use the max value of the datatype, e.g. 32767 for smallint or 255 for tinyint.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Type1 VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('Below 50 (Red) '),
('50<100 (Orange)'),
('150<200 (Green)'),
('200 Above(Blue)');

DECLARE @Num INT = -1;

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE Type1 LIKE 
      '%' +
      (CASE WHEN @Num >= 0 AND @Num <= 50 THEN 'Red'
            WHEN @Num > 50 AND @Num <= 100 THEN 'Orange'
            WHEN @Num > 100 AND @Num <= 200 THEN 'Green'
            WHEN @Num > 200 THEN 'Blue'
            ELSE
            NULL
       END
      ) + '%';
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=213d411a197416407ac1866dea13e2b2)**

Comment: @NamanKumar Great, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a `case` expression?

```
select (case when value < 50 then 'red'
             when value < 100 then 'orange'
             when value < 200 then 'green'
             else 'blue'
        end) as color
```

I assume that 100-150 is green in this example.  It is left out of the question.

Comment: I don't think so, it's just a sample and maybe there is a lot of colors in a lot of ranges.

Comment: Yeah it's something like that .. but i have data in table which i need to compare.

Comment: No @Sami there is limited data in it. Only Four colors are for Type 1,2,3,4